# unbiased estimator for sample covariance?

Tags: statistics, estimation

I'm new to statistics and and I need some help:

Let $X_1,...X_n$~$N(\mu_x,\sigma^2)$, $Y_1,...Y_m$~$N(\mu_y,\sigma^2)$.
All r.vs. are i.i.d and $\mu_x,\mu_y,\sigma$ are unknown

I was told that $S_p^2=(S_x^2(n-1)+S_y^2(m-1))/(n+m-2)$ is an unbiased estimator for the sample covariance.

I think I'm confused over definitions because to my best of knowledge covariance cannot be calculated when $n\not=m$. Am I correct? if so what is the above actually an unbiased estimator of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  If you cannot match up realizations from $X$ with realizations from $Y$, then it is impossible to estimate how $X$ and $Y$ vary together; i.e., their covariance.  What is required to estimate covariance are **pairs** of realizations between the variables.

The estimator you cite is the **pooled variance** of two samples assumed to be drawn from distributions with possibly different means, but with the same variance.  That is to say, your $S_p^2$ is an estimator of $\sigma^2$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and normally distributed with different means but the same variance.  But if $X$ and $Y$ are marginal distributions from a bivariate normal with unknown mean vector $\boldsymbol \mu = (\mu_x, \mu_y)$ and covariance matrix $$\boldsymbol \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_x^2 & \sigma_{xy} \\ \sigma_{xy} & \sigma_y^2 \end{bmatrix},$$ where in your case we might assume $\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_y^2 = \sigma^2$, then $S_p^2$ does **not** in any way estimate $\sigma_{xy}$.  In fact, such a sample cannot estimate the covariance for the reason given in the previous paragraph.